# Wrong rotation calculated if parent object has negative scale Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2019.4.15f1.

In my game, I'm simply trying to rotate the arm of my enemy character to point its gun at my player.
Everything works fine when the object has +ve scale. But for the negative scale same angle value result in different output.

I'm just setting the angle of the arm with this code.

```
arm.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 59f);
```

At run-time even if I change the scale to +ve it works fine but on changing it negative again different results.

This is the output for +ve and -ve scale

[image]

At run-time, if we change scale between +ve and -ve it still shows different output.

At run-time this is the output.

Comment: what is the rotation in the inspector for the guns?

Comment: @Simonster For the +ve one its 59 and for negative one its 100.

Comment: Is there any other code that might change the rotation of the arm? I couldn't recreate this issue and I can't think of anything that would cause this.

Comment: One thing is the direction of the arm that need to point towards the player, the other thing is the graphics. The arm transform should always point to the player for all possible angels, simply make it "look at" the player every frame. The other aspect has to do with the correct graphics visualization. I assume you want your arms to be mirrored when passing from one side to the other, thus you will have to do mirroring based on the angle between the pointing direction and the vertical line, if the angle is positive you apply mirroring or viceversa.